# Testing with Laravel: DatabaseTransactions or DatabaseMigrations

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

`DatabaseTransactions` trait seems to be faster than `DatabaseMigrations` trait in Laravel tests. It's normal, because for each test `DatabaseMigrations` runs all migration process (+rollback) again, and `DatabaseTransactions` just cancels the last transaction. It seems sensible to choose `DatabaseTransactions` trait then.

Still, `DatabaseMigrations` does exist. So, **is there any benefits in using it** (instead of using `DatabaseTransactions`)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are likely a number of pros and cons, but for me the two main benefits of DatabaseMigrations are:

1) You don't need to maintain a test database. If you're using DatabaseTransactions you need to ensure that your test DB schema is up to date with your normal DB schema. Not difficult to do, just an extra thing to keep track of.

2) Using DatabaseMigrations allows you to use an in-memory SQLite DB for testing, which is faster and more lightweight than MySQL or Postgres.

Overall I don't think there is a right or wrong answer though - I think it just comes down to preference.